# Deploying .war file to tomcat in bash

Tags: java, bash, maven, tomcat

I need to deploy a the file person-search-service.war to a tomcat(9.0.38) server. Previously, the project was exported as a .war in eclipse and added to the server that way. The issue is, this needs to be deployed to a headless machine, so obviously it cannot be done the way it has been done in development. At the end of the day, I just need to be able to write a script that auto-deploys the webapp. What I have been trying(which works with dummy projects like [this one](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/appdev/sample/)) is `jar -cvf person-search-service.war person-search-service/` to create the .war file, then moving it to the $CATALINA_HOME/webapps directory and starting tomcat with the $CATALINA_HOME/bin/startup.sh script. More simply, from the directory where the project exists, I am running:

```
jar -cvf person-search-service.war person-search-service/
mv person-search-service.war $CATALINA_HOME/webapps
$CATALINA_HOME/bin/startup.sh
```

Then navigating to the configured path localhost:8080/person-search-service/person yields the apache 404 page. As I said, this works perfectly with eclipse, and I just need to replicate the behavior exclusively in terminal.

The JDK I am using is AdoptOpenJDK(version 8). It also might be worth mentioning that this project uses maven(3.6.3), though I am not sure if/how that would affect anything, though I suspect the primary issue might be with how the project is being exported, or have to do with the classpath somehow.

*EDIT*

The most recent catalina.out logs are:

```
15-Oct-2020 17:12:09.857 INFO [main] org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSourceFactory.getObjectInstance Name = h2 Ignoring unknown property: value of "Datasource to person database" for "description" property
15-Oct-2020 17:12:10.059 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deploying web application archive [/mnt/c/dev/tools/apache-tomcat-9.0.38-windows-x64/apache-tomcat-9.0.38/webapps/person-search-service.war]
15-Oct-2020 17:12:10.772 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deployment of web application archive [/mnt/c/dev/tools/apache-tomcat-9.0.38-windows-x64/apache-tomcat-9.0.38/webapps/person-search-service.war] has finished in [712] ms
```

The part concerning h2 can likely be ignored, it didnt work before I added that.

Comment: Is Tomcat running?  The `source` command will not do what you want.  Rather just run `$CATALINA_HOME/bin/startup.sh` and it will start up.  It seems like it is if you're getting a Tomcat 404 page.  Next, take a look in `$CATALINA_HOME/logs/catalina.out` and see if you're getting any error messages.  Post those messages to see if there is something we can help with.

Comment: I changed the command to just the startup.sh, to no avail. I have edited the question to contain the server logs